# Is there a function that maps $\mathbb{R}$ to {$-1,1$}

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, integers

I know how to map a set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or integers $\mathbb{Z}$ to an interval, e.g. $[0,1]$, but how would I do it for a set containing two elements? I know such a set would not be injective, though, that's for sure. Suggestions?

Comment: How about the function $f(x) = 1$? Or did you want it to be onto / surjective?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 0$, $-1$ else. This is a surjection.

Comment: @Arthur surjective's useful here too. If it isn't surjective, then there's no point in including the ${-1}$ in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want this function to *do*. The constant functions $x\mapsto -1$ or $x\mapsto 1$ do the job. Or maybe you want a surjection? Then how about $x\mapsto 1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $x\mapsto -1$ otherwise; or $x\mapsto 1$ if $x\not=17$, and $17\mapsto -1$; or so on.

Comment: The "so on" is pretty big, considering there's $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ such functions.

Comment: Whoa, if we considered the set of all the possible such functions, then that set would be uncountably infinite. Would it be bigger than $\mathbb{R}$? Just curious :)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Well, up to isomorphism in the category of sets there are only countably many, so that's not so bad! :P

Comment: @Xpert The set of all maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\{-1, 1\}$ is indeed of greater cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$. Specifically, given any *set* $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we can produce a *map* $\chi_A: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{-1, 1\}$ given by $\chi_A(x)=1$ iff $x\in A$; and conversely, given any *map* $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{-1, 1\}$, we can get a *set* $\sigma_f=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)=1\}$. Indeed, examining these we have a bijection between $\{$maps $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{-1, 1\}\}$ and $\{$subsets of $\mathbb{R}\}$; now apply [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem)!

Comment: @Xpert Interestingly, questions about *how big* are these gaps between these levels of infinity - $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ - are **provably not answerable** using the usual axioms of set theory, ZFC! In particular, the statement "There is no 'level of infinity' between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$" - the [Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) - was proved independent of ZFC by Goedel and Cohen, and Cohen's part of the proof (the harder one) marked the birth of really modern set theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you mean Goedel and Cohen proved that they cannot prove it, hence why it's still a hypothesis, not a Theorem :)

Comment: @Xpert They proved that one can neither prove *nor disprove* it, from the axioms of ZFC. Specifically, Goedel showed that CH is *consistent* with ZFC, so can't be *disproved*, by developing the theory of the [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), $L$, and inner models in general; and Cohen showed that $\neg$CH is consistent with ZFC, so CH can't be *proved*, by developing the theory of [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)). Interestingly, forcing can also be used to show that CH is consistent with ZFC - it's much more versatile.

Comment: @Xpert Another weird fact: you can't prove, from ZFC alone, that if $X$ has bigger cardinality than $Y$ then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has bigger cardinality than $\mathcal{P}(Y)$! (By "bigger" I mean "strictly bigger": obviously if $X$ is *at least* as big as $Y$, then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is *at least* as big as $\mathcal{P}(Y)$.) Indeed, there are reasonably natural set-theoretic hypotheses - such as the [Proper Forcing Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom) - which imply that this statement is **false**!

Comment: @NoahSchweber that is weird, logically, that statement should hold. It does in the finite case. Strange things happen when we deal with infinity! :)

Answer (score 0):

Choose some subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&x\in A\\ -1&x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus A\end{array}\right.
$$
is such a function (and every other function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\{-1,1\}$ is of this form).